# Procmail standard base path for directory delivery

Tags: directory, procmail

I had trouble with procmail not wanting to deliver my mail to a specific folder. I had:

```
DEFAULT=/home/vmail/${ER_DOMAIN}/${ER_USER}/

:0
* ^To:.*my-email
* ^Subject:.*some-filter
.the-dir/
```

But got errors like:

```
procmail: Unable to treat as directory ".the-dir"
```

I changed the last line of the procmail rule to:

```
/home/vmail/$ER_DOMAIN/$ER_USER/.the-dir/
```

To give procmail the whole path, and that works.

Is there a way I can give procmail a base path, so that I don't have to put the full path in every rule? Is there a standard procmail-way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEFAULT` is the path to the default mailbox file. (It can be a directory with maildir, but it's still one mailbox, not something that's treated as a directory with subdirectories).

You want `MAILDIR`.

> Current  directory  while procmail is executing (that means that all paths are relative to `$MAILDIR`).